# SQL Server 2014 - Offset with fetch next

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run this code, but I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
>
> Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
>   Invalid use of the NEXT option in the FETCH statement.

This is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbp.Expats_Gesamt AS P
ORDER BY P.last_name
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Tag the `SQL Server` version that you are using. You can check it 
`select @@VERSION`.

Comment: I can't replicate the error on SQL Server 2012, nor on fiddle. [dd<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd8f3ec7fdc419c4c06b92250e9ba020)

Comment: Check the compatibility level of your database. `OFFSET-FETCH` should only parse correctly at level 110 or higher.

Comment: use `dbo.` instead of `dbp`

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests `FETCH . . . OFFSET` clause error that means your current version that don't support it or might be version compatibility issue (you can check & set accordingly) however i don't know which version you are using.

So, i would try with `subquery` instead that would support for lower version :

```
select top (20) p.*
from (select top (30) P.*
      from dbp.Expats_Gesamt AS P
      order by P.last_name
     ) p
order by P.last_name desc;
```

Comment: Considering that the OP has put "SQL Server 2014" in the question's subject, I *suspect* the problem is the compatibility level, and not the version of the Software.

Comment: @Larnu. . . That i realized on my second last edit made.